# error in coverting decimal value from tracking device to DD | MM | YY | HH | MM | SS | MS

Tags: java

The below is the code where I'm trying to convert a decimal value from my device to timestamp/timespan data, but I'm not getting the right answer, i.e. I need to get `12:59:59` but instead I have it as `13:00:00`.

```
double dec = 913707042;
int sec = (int)Math.round(dec * 3600);
int deg = sec / 3600;
sec = Math.abs(sec % 3600);
int min = sec / 60;
sec %= 60;
```

I don't understand what is wrong with this code, please kindly help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is hour calculated?

Comment: Which timestamp is `913707042` supposed to represent?

Comment: What does the `913707042` mean? Is it number of seconds? Number of wing-flaps of European swallow? We can't help you without context.

Comment: BTW, since `dec` represents a number of seconds and is even, you cannot expect to get `12:59:59`!

Comment: its just a hex value coverted into a 32 bit decimal which needs to be converted into Date | Month | Year | Date | Hour | Min | Seconds

Comment: You shouldn't be using round and abs.  You don't want rounding and if you get a negative value it's because you mucked something up.

Comment: And it's not clear -- are you trying to calculate time or an angle??  In fact, what the heck ARE you trying to calculate?

Comment: Never mind -- second example was bogusly inserted by someone else.

Comment: Again, what is the definition of your input value???  (You realize that the formula you're using is for degrees/minutes/seconds, right?)

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is here:

```
double dec = 913707042;
int sec = (int)Math.round(dec * 3600);
```

`dec * 3600` gives you a number too large to fit into an integer (up to 2^31 - 1) so your casting the return value to `(int)` will lose some precision.

However, the real problem is that your code is rather odd:

```
int sec = (int)Math.round(dec * 3600);
int deg = sec / 3600;
sec = Math.abs(sec % 3600);
```

Why not just say:

```
int deg = (int) dec;
int sec = deg % 3600;
```

If you do that, you should also solve your loss of a second.

Comment: Yes the **round** ing to an entire second is the culprit. Truncation is done with casting a double to int: `(int) dec`.